svelte config custom path for app.html does not work
Im restructuring my project (website). Now it has:

src/frontend/...

src/backend/...


I changed my svelte.config.js to have the specific path:
files: {
        appTemplate: 'src/frontend/src/app.html',
    },

But I still get the error:
src/app.html does not exist


Is the config in the right place, i.e. in kit?

The files and other configs need to be inside the kit element in the svelte.config.js.
